# Сортировка списка по динамическому количеству полей

Tags: c#, сортировка, linq

Есть лист, который сортируется по двум полям GroupingLevel1 и GroupingLevel2 с помощью linq. Но количество этих уровней будет увеличиваться Groupinglevel3...GroupingLevelN. Как написать универсальную сортировку, независимо от количества полей?

```
var destObjectsCurrent = destObjects.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.PropValues["GroupingLevel1"].PropertyValue.ToString()).ThenByDescending(x => 
x.PropValues["GroupingLevel2"].PropertyValue.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Просто обернуть в цикл

Comment: последующие сортировки не должны сбиваться предыдущими, поэтому цикл не подходит

Comment: Не сортировать в цикле, а добавлять `ThenByDescending`

Comment: `последующие сортировки не должны сбиваться предыдущими` вы определитесь, что у вас приоритетней в сортировке, предыдущие или последующие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, имеются следующие классы:

```
public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, Prop> PropValues { get; set; }
}

public class Prop
{
    public int PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Имеется коллекция объектов:

```
var destObjects = new List<Test>
{
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel1", new Prop { PropertyValue = 3 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel3", new Prop { PropertyValue = 6 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel2", new Prop { PropertyValue = 4 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel2", new Prop { PropertyValue = 7 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel3", new Prop { PropertyValue = 2 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel1", new Prop { PropertyValue = 8 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel1", new Prop { PropertyValue = 5 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel3", new Prop { PropertyValue = 9 } } } },
    new Test { PropValues = new Dictionary<string, Prop> { { "GroupingLevel2", new Prop { PropertyValue = 1 } } } },
};
```

Я сохранил логику вашего кода. Вероятно, можно сделать проще.
Сортируем и выводим:

```
// Получаем список ключей
var keys = destObjects.SelectMany(x => x.PropValues.Keys).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

IOrderedEnumerable<Test> ordered = destObjects.OrderByDescending(x =>
{
    if (x.PropValues.TryGetValue(keys[0], out Prop prop))
        return prop.PropertyValue.ToString();
    else
        return null;
});

// Динамически добавляем сортировку
for (int i = 1; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(x =>
        x.PropValues.TryGetValue(keys[j], out var prop)
        ? prop.PropertyValue.ToString()
        : null);
}

var result = ordered.ToList();

foreach (var r in result)
    foreach (var t in r.PropValues)
        Console.WriteLine(t.Key + " " + t.Value.PropertyValue);
```

Можно объявить `var ordered`. Полный тип использован для наглядности.

В одном случае я использовал оператор `if - else`, в другом - тернарный оператор. Результат одинаков. Решите сами, какой способ записи понятней.